# CSS and images static files are loading however js are not

Tags: javascript, python, django, static

`urls.py:`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from registration import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from registration.views import index

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/,
     url(r'^index/', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),

)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

`local.py`

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="{% static 'app_name/js/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app_name/js/highcharts-3d.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app_name/js/exporting.js' %}"></script>
```

I am loading my css and images in the same manner as the above js files stated above. The images and CSS load perfectly fine. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you images and where are your js files located? Did you try putting them in the same folder?

Comment: Yes. My js files are in `static/app_name/js/...` and my images are in `static/app_name/images/...`

Comment: did u collect your static file using python manage.py collectstatic ?

Comment: No. I am still in development mode so should I still do that?

Comment: The file must be the name of the file the output link suffix. There is also another application check files with the headers are correct.

Comment: @SDilmac I didn't complete get your point. Could you please give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The STATIC_ROOT setting is not used in development mode. It's only used when collecting static files with the 'collectstatic' management command. By default, static files are looked for in every installed app's subdirectory with the name 'static' and additionally any directory mentioned in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting.

Also, if you have DEBUG=True somewhere in your settings, you don't need to specifically add staticfiles_urlpatterns to your urls.py file. It's done automatically.

Assuming the following:

- your goal is to look for static files in a default django 'project'
  and so you don't have a separate django 'app' in your INSTALLED_APPS
  setting.
- your indexview can find your index.html template, you didn't
  post
- your view your project directory structure looks like this:

folder structure:

```
myproject
-manage.py
-myproject
-myproject>__init__.py
-myproject>urls.py
-myproject>settings.py
-myproject>wsgi.py
-staticfiles
-staticfiles>js>highcharts.js
```

Then, try this:

in `settings.py` (showing only relevant settings)

```
DEBUG=True
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),
)
```

and in `index.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'js/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am looking for the static files of an app in the project. And my settings are in a settings directory which has local, production and base files.

Comment: In that case you should have put your js file in `app_name/static/highcharts.js` and use `<script src="{% static 'js/highcharts.js' %}"></script>` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was some syntactical error in the javascript files. Resolved. Thanks everyone for your help.